# Celery worker dies after random time with IronMQ

Tags: python, django, celery, ironmq, django-supervisor

Running Django 1.4.10, Celery 3.1.7, Python 2.7, Kombu 3.0.12, and using django supervisor to run both celery worker and celery beat as a daemon. Using IronMQ as the broker.

Everything works fine processing periodic tasks for a number of days, then all of a sudden the worker will just die fatally:

```
[2014-08-04 16:52:17,647: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: TypeError("sequence index must be integer, not 'unicode'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/celery-3.1.7-py2.7.egg/celery/worker  /__init__.py", line 206, in start
self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/celery-3.1.7-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
step.start(parent)
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/celery-3.1.7-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 373, in start
return self.obj.start()
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/celery-3.1.7-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 270, in start
blueprint.start(self)
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/celery-3.1.7-py2.7.egg/celery/bootsteps.py", line 123, in start
step.start(parent)
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/celery-3.1.7-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 786, in start
c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/celery-3.1.7-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/loops.py", line 99, in synloop
connection.drain_events(timeout=2.0)
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/kombu-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/kombu/connection.py", line 279, in drain_events
return self.transport.drain_events(self.connection, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/kombu-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 844, in drain_events
self._callbacks[queue](message)
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/kombu-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 529, in _callback
message = self.Message(self, raw_message)
  File "/home/kromedev/webapps/gorilla/lib/python2.7/kombu-3.0.12-py2.7.egg/kombu/transport/virtual/__init__.py", line 242, in __init__
properties = payload['properties']
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'unicode'
```

Looking at the timestamp, it always seems to crash way after the tasks are all finished. As I have my supervisor.conf file to autorestart, it then goes into a loop trying to restart the worker and failing instantly. However, if I shut down all processes with supervisor and restart, it all works again for a few days.

Supervisor.conf:

```
[program:celeryd]
command={{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celery worker -l info
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile={{ PROJECT_DIR }}/worker.log
stderr_logfile={{ PROJECT_DIR }}/worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
killasgroup=true
priority=998

[program:celerybeat]
command={{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celery beat  -l INFO
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile={{ PROJECT_DIR }}/beat.log
stderr_logfile={{ PROJECT_DIR }}/beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
priority=999
```

No idea where to even begin to debug this one - throwing it out there incase anyone else has had the same issue and can throw some light on it.

UPDATE: I switched back to trusty Erlang/Rabbit and the issue completely disappeared. So it's IronMQ. I couldn't really get any help from them about it, so they lost a customer!